# asp.net identity2 , how do i get the name of the user in a seperate class (in a dll), ie from our libraries

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Asp.net identity2 , how do I get the name of the user in a seperate class (in a dll), ie from our libraries...

all the samples on SO seem to assume you are in a Controller

Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core v2.0.0.0
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin

.Net 4.5.2

MVC 5.

when I try the controller style, in my class, User is not defined

I assume I'm missing a reference, but I was unable to guess which..

Comment: What exactly are you trying?  How is your "other class" related to the application?  If the user is a dependency of the other class, then the controller should probably provide it to that class in some way.

Comment: I'm adapting a forms app to run under asp.net identity using google to authenticate, in the library I currently write the users name, etc into the session, so other parts of the library can fetch it on demand, I want to make a new method in the existing library that can get it... whether or not it's being called from the controller.

Comment: The `Controller.User` property is an `IPrincipal` object (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.user.aspx).  You could simply pass that to your code that needs information about the user.  (Or even just pass the string value of the username if that's all the code needs.)  I wouldn't recommend creating dependencies on things like `System.Web` or `System.Web.Mvc` in your class libraries.

Comment: So there is no way to get the current user outside of a controller... weird.

Comment: Well, outside the context of the application layer (the controller), the concept of a "user" doesn't really mean much.  It seems likely that the framework populates the `User` property from information in the current `HttpContext`.  (Though I'm not 100% certain.)  You *could* make references to `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` in your code.  But, again, this is very much not recommended.  This would mean that your class libraries can *only* ever be used in the context of a web application and are tightly coupled to that context. Just provide your class libraries with the information they need.

Comment: `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User`. However, as David says, it is a bad practice to couple your library with this. better to pass a reference of `IPrinciple` or other information required.

Comment: My whole problem was that part of my code was executing before System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User was getting populated, I'm going with passing the Principal.